# Power series with simple recurrence relationship: $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} - \frac{1}{4}a_n$. How to determine corresponding closed form function?

Tags: power-series

Given:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n = f(x)$$

where:

$$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} - \frac{1}{4}a_n$$

is the recurrence relationship for $a_2$ and above ($a_0$ and $a_1$ are also given).

Is there a nice closed form to this pretty recurrence relationship?

Comment: $$a_{n+2}x^{n+2} = x.a_{n+1}x^{n+1} - x^2\frac{1}{4}a_nx^n$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff What is $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: here the characteristic polynomial has a double root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Solving your recurrence relationship gives
$$
a_n=c_12^{-n}+c_2n2^{-n},
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be determined by $a_0$ and $a_1$.

You will end up calculating the sums
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)^n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} n\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)^n
$$
Do you know how to do that? Ask to fill in details where necessary...

Comment: Thanks for the hint based answer! I am very new to series, so I think I know how to do the first sum, but maybe not the second -- however, I *will* look up how to do so and come back to you :)

Comment: How did you "solve" the recurrence relationship?

Comment: As Jack writes, the characteristic equation is $x^2-x+1/4=0$ which has the double root $x=1/2$. Then (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)) one get that $a_n=c_1(1/2)^n+c_2n(1/2)^n=c_12^{-n}+c_2n2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence
$$ a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{4}a_n \tag{1}$$
is $p(x) = x^2-x+\frac{1}{4} = \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$, we have that $$\left(2-x\right)^2\, f(x) = ax+b\tag{2}$$
where $a,b$ depend on the initial conditions. By decomposing $\frac{ax+b}{(2-x)^2}$ into partial fractions, we get:
$$ a_n = 2^{-(n+2)} (b+(2 a+b) n). \tag{3}$$

Comment: @mickep: ok, you are right, now fixed.